# Cannot use storm command line interface to kill topology

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-storm

I have a storm cluster, my storm version is 0.10.1, and it run well. I can kill topology using ui in browser which is good. But sometime I want to just kill topology by shell. When I run this: `bin/storm kill topology_name`, I get errors.

```
Exception in thread "main" NotAliveException(msg:com_adsame_mydmp is not alive)
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$killTopologyWithOpts_result$killTopologyWithOpts_resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:7482)
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$killTopologyWithOpts_result$killTopologyWithOpts_resultStandardScheme.read(Nimbus.java:7468)
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$killTopologyWithOpts_result.read(Nimbus.java:7410)
at org.apache.thrift7.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.recv_killTopologyWithOpts(Nimbus.java:283)
at backtype.storm.generated.Nimbus$Client.killTopologyWithOpts(Nimbus.java:269)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93)
at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28)
at backtype.storm.command.kill_topology$_main.doInvoke(kill_topology.clj:27)
at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
at backtype.storm.command.kill_topology.main(Unknown Source)
```

But I can see this topology activate when I execute `bin/storm list`.

```
 Topology_name        Status     Num_tasks  Num_workers  Uptime_secs
-------------------------------------------------------------------
    topology_name        ACTIVE     73         4            423894
```

Any idea ? Thanks.

Comment: Is this still an issue? Based on the stack you posted you could be passing an option (`killTopologyWithOpts`), the only option is `wait_secs`. Are you sure you are using `kill topology_name` and not `kill topology_name {wait_secs}`?

Comment: Sorry, I reply later. I just solve this problem.

Comment: I have solved this problem. My topology name tailed with one space which I did not notice. When I give a topology name  to kill command, the shell just strip the space, so the topology name was different.